# iPhone: Reassignment of instance variable = deallocation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an instance variable NSMutableArray* searchResults.

First, I initialize it:

```
self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then, at the course of my app, it gets reassigned frequently:

```
NSMutableArray* results = [searcher getResults];
self.searchResults = results;
```

My question is will this cause a memory leak because the array it pointed to previously may not get deallocated during this reassignment? Do I explicitly need to do this:

```
NSMutableArray* results = [searcher getResults];
self.searchResults = nil;
self.searchResults = results;
```

Of course, I release it in dealloc, and set it to nil in viewDidUnload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may have a memory leak, but not for the reasons you think.  The answer depends on how your property was declared, and whether you're releasing the object after you allocate it.

When declaring a property that your object owns (as opposed to something like a delegate, which is owned by a different object), you typically declare it like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
```

I'm assuming this is how your property is declared.  The `retain` clause of that declaration means that an object will automatically be retained whenever it is assigned through this property's setter method (i.e. either through `self.searchResults = foo` or `[self setSearchResults:foo];`).

If the property already references an existing object, then the `retain` clause causes that existing object to be automatically released when the property gets reassigned.  So setting `self.searchResults = nil;` prior to doing another assignment does indeed cause that existing object to be released, but this really isn't necessary because `self.searchResults = results;` also releases any existing object before it retains and stores the new reference.

You may have a memory leak on this line:

```
self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

After this line, your retain count is +2.  It got +1 for the alloc, and +1 for the property assignment.  This creates a memory leak, unless you have `[self.searchResults release]` elsewhere in your method.  The way I'd fix it is like this:

```
self.searchResults = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Whenever you're confused about memory management, it's always worthwhile to go back and reread the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Another way to initialise the property would be to do `searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, i.e. not assigning to the property but to the ivar instead.

Comment: That's true, although it's a risky habit to get into, IMO.  If searchResults happens to point to an existing object when you do an assignment like that, that object will get leaked.  I prefer to just use dot-properties consistently for all my instance variable assignments.  It gives my feeble brain one less thing to think about.

Comment: I only do this in an initializer (`init` or `initXYZ:` methods). I assume that is only called once.

Comment: Fair enough. Different strokes for different folks. :)

Comment: Another option (available for most of the frequently-used Cocoa classes) is the convenience constructor, e.g., `self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array]`.

Answer (score 2):

If the `@property` was declared with `retain` or `copy` and it was created by `@synthesize`, there is no memory leak. If that is not the case, you could have one, depending on the implementation of the method.

Comment: Now, I'm confused. So what Saphrosit said below is not correct? I do have a retain, and synthesize

Comment: If the property was declared with retain, the compiler will generate a setter that releases the previous value and retains the new one, if they are different. Assuming the getResults method returns an autoreleased array, there is no memory management issue.

Comment: FWIW, it seems the other answer was retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

if you have declared the property as retain, for self.searchResults, you should assign an autoreleased instance. i.e.
header file:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *searchResults;
```

implementation file:

```
@synthesize searchResults;
self.searchResults=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

if you have a synthesise a property with retain, it will create setters and getters for you.
self.searchResults will call a function something like this:

```
-(void)setSearchResults:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    if(searchResults!=array){
        [searchResults autorelease];
        searchResults = [array retain];
    }
}
```

so you can do this without having to worry:

```
self.searchResults=[searcher getResults];
```